# How to find methodAction by name

Tags: symfony, methods, routes, symfony-2.8

I am beginner in a new project, and I don't know files/dir structure...

I found this in code:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
```

I need know what `methodAction` belong to `fos_user_security_check` name path,

Does it exist some command line look for ?

My symfony version is **2.8.28**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php app/console debug:router [name_route]
```